# Как правильно распараллелить создание объектов

Tags: c#, parallel

Всем привет!
Есть необходимость создать большое количество (n) однотипных объектов, а потом их отсортировать.
Решил сделать это многопоточно. Собсвенно встал вопрос, как это сделать максимально правильно.
Есть мысль: создать четыре потока, в каждом насоздавать по объекту-коллекции содержащему n/4 объектов. Затем склеить объекты-коллекции в один лист и его отсортировать. Но в таком случае требуемая память разрастается при создании дубликатов. Какие еще есть варианты?

Comment: большое количество это сколько? и откуда у вас будут дубликаты?

Comment: Большое - миллион. А дубликаты,  получаются когда я из 4 маленьких объектов-коллекций достаю список и запихиваю их в большой объект-коллекцию для сортировки. Типа BigList.AddRange(listSmallObjects[0].SmallList)

Comment: Откуда вообще возникла мысль о необходимости многопоточности? Объекты тяжеловесные и их создание происходит долго?

Comment: Да, объекты создаются через рандом с проверкой условий... в общем занимает время. Ну и хотелось бы для себя понять сам принцип

Comment: дак память то у вас разрастается только на N указателей новых, сами объекты то в одном экземпляре остаются. А если создаются рандомно, то нельзя ли сделать это менее рандомно, чтобы они сразу сортированными создавались? и в целом тут сортировка слиянием напрашивается

Comment: Вот и я считаю, что в первую очередь нужно оптимизировать создание: делать его менее рандомным.

Comment: Да, насчет создания услышал. Но вопрос в распараллеливании

Comment: Зайдём с начала. Откуда берутся дубликаты? По каким параметрам объекты должны сравниваться/различаться? Почему проблема с дубликатами возникает только при слиянии коллекций? Почему её нет в каждом отдельном потоке? Или всё же есть? Можете вы решить проблему дубликатов при генерации объектов в _одном_ потоке?